# i can see search icon on my actionbar even though i have not implemented searchquery listener in my fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, search, widget, searchview

i can see search icon on my actionbar even though i have not implemented searchquery listener in my fragment android,

Prior to this i have a fragment that holds viewpager in which there are two fragments(FragA and FragB) with list...i have implemented SearchQueryListener and implement OCreateOptionMenu in both FragA and FragB,, on item click of FragA and FragB i want to add another fragment that keeps the detail of item but when i add that new fragment i am able to see the same search icon on topbar..when click on that search icon my app crash because search icon dowsnt belong to this current fragment..
Please help me to resolve how to get this fix.. i want to have Search icon only where i have implemented onCreateOptionMenu method..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the search icon contained in any layout?

Comment: Yes @gymni 

it is kept in the menu.xml

Comment: Have you tried to implement onPrepareOptionsMenu in the MainActivity? Based on the position of the fragment show or hide menu element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either of the below options,

```
@Override 
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); 
menu.removeItem(id)
}
```

or

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```

Comment: i have already tried this but it doesn't work ...
i think it is the problem because i am setting search icon from child fragments and new fragment that comes in the picture is replacing parent fragment...
i am not sure what is happening :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your new fragment that you are adding, where "action_search" is the search icon id in menu.xml:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);      
    return true;
 }
```